# gather elements by value in list python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 2-D lists:

```
lst = [[8, 301],[8, 303],[8, 305],[8, 307],[8, 309],
[4, 351],[3, 359],[3, 361],[4, 364],[4, 365],
[3, 368],[1, 375],[1, 376],[8, 417]]
```

and I want to gather sequence elements by the first cell of the element. the expected result will be:

```
out = [[8, 301],[4, 351],[3, 359],[4, 364],
[3, 368],[1, 375],[8, 417]]
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from `itertools` like,

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x
[[8, 301], [8, 303], [8, 305], [8, 307], [8, 309], [4, 351], [3, 359], [3, 361], [4, 364], [4, 365], [3, 368], [1, 375], [1, 376], [8, 417]]
>>>
>>> [next(grp) for _,grp in itertools.groupby(x, lambda l: l[0])]
[[8, 301], [4, 351], [3, 359], [4, 364], [3, 368], [1, 375], [8, 417]]
```